# How to call the recursive call at last if it meets the condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I have nested object called option. It has nested (potentially infinite) objects called `childOptions` key.

```
option = {
  name: 'o1', label: 'o1', childOptions: [
    { name: 'o4', label: 'o4', childOptions: [
      {name: 'o5', label: 'o5',
    ]},
    { name: 'o2', label: 'o3'},
    { name: 'o3', label: 'o3'}
  ]
}
```

This is my render function to render JSX based on that.

```
  function renderOption(option): JSX.Element {
    if (option.childOptions) {
      return (
        <li
          key={option.name}
        >
          <span>
            {option.label}
          </span>
          <ul>
            {option.childOptions.map(renderOption} << recursive call!
          </ul>
        </li>
      );
    }
```

I have nested `option` object which passes into `renderOption`

This is the current output (**CORRECT But not what I want**)

```
<li>
  <span>o1</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>o4</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>o5</span></li>
      <ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>o2</span></li>
    <li><span>o3</span></li>
  </ul>    
</li>
```

Because we show o2 and o5 right after o1, user gets confused to read.
**This is what I need**

```
<li>
  <span>o1</span>
  <ul>
    <li><span>o2</span></li>
    <li><span>o3</span></li>
    <li>
      <span>o4</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>o5</span></li>
      <ul>
    <li>
  </ul>    
</li>
```

I think it might be not possible. How do we call the recursive call at last if it meets the condition?

- I still want to keep the recursive call if we could.

Comment: There is no `o2` in the `option` object

Comment: The outputs you shared do not correspond to the input. There is an unbalanced parenthesis in your code.

Comment: sorry guys; editing ...

Comment: It's fixed; sorry . I think it got messed up while cpying and pasting

Comment: Unbalanced brace in your first block. Please... take time to post correct code.

Comment: If you want o4 to come after o3, you should fix the order in your input array?

Comment: How confused will the reader get when there are multiple elements that have children? Unless the structure is more restricted than you've told us, you probably should fix your design (e.g. adding indentation) instead of confusing the user even more by re-ordering the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the `childOptions` in your object by name:

```
  function renderOption(option): JSX.Element {
    if (option.childOptions) {

      option.childOptions.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

      return (
        <li
          key={option.name}
        >
          <span>
            {option.label}
          </span>
          <ul>
            {option.childOptions.map(renderOption} << recursive call!
          </ul>
        </li>
      );
    }
```

Comment: holly crab genius

Answer (score 0):

You could return a `ul` for an array of options. Get the array of options as props to the function component. Pass the initial `option` object as an array to make it uniform and easier to make a recursive call

Here's a runnable snippet:

```js
const option={name:"o1",label:"o1",childOptions:[{name:"o4",label:"o4",childOptions:[{name:"o5",label:"o5"}]},{name:"o2",label:"o2"},{name:"o3",label:"o3"}]};

function Display({ options }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {options.map(c => (
        <li key={c.name}>
          <span>{c.label}</span>
          {c.childOptions && <Display options={c.childOptions} />}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Display options={[option]} />, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```